# Mac OS - How to disable pf on boot

Tags: macos, firewall, pf

So, after months of hunting to work out why Private Relay isn't working, I eventually tracked it down to the fact that pf is running.  When I disable pf with `sudo pfctl -d` then private relay becomes active.

I have no idea why pf is running on this machine.  To my knowledge I have never enabled it.  `etc/pf.conf` looks to be set to its default:

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
```

How do I either figure out what is starting pf on boot and remove it, or prevent pf from starting so that Private Relay can work?

Comment: Do the opposite of https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308182/how-to-launch-pf-at-startup